Which statistical test should I use for 3 independent variables and one dependent variable?
What are the tests that I can use for 3 independent variables (ordinal - Likert) and 1 dependent variable (college grades - general average)?
I am trying to see if the IV really affects their GWA (DV) or not.
Thank you!

Are your hypotheses about the IVs' effects main effect hypotheses or do you hypothesize also interactive effects between IVs? In any case it sounds like linear regression with all 3 IVs as predictors would be a good place to start.
Here is one guide for SPSS and here for R; there are tons of tutorials online.
After running the model, check whether the regression assumptions hold; if yes, great, if not, you need to consider some changes or other modeling approaches.
